# getting react error messages showing on the broweser, not only in the console

Tags: reactjs

I created a new JS file for react, however, i didn't export yet thus i got the below error message in the browser console
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at index.js:9.

My issue is, that the error is not showing up on the actual browser like the image below
[image from actual browesr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0xRU.png)

Comment: Which react version you are using?

Comment: version is 18.2.0

Answer (score -1):

That overlay is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-overlay, it's a convenience included in create-react-app (and I believe some other starter kits).

If you're not seeing that overlay but expect to, install that package and make sure you're running your build locally, with hot reload turned on.

Comment: Do you have instructions on how to run it?

Comment: I've only ever used this particular module preinstalled as part of create-react-app, but I'd expect the standard installation methods would work as for any other NPM module. `npm i react-error-overlay --save-dev`

Comment: i ran this, i actually see it in my packgage.json but it didn't do anything

Comment: Sorry you're having trouble with it.  You may want to open that as a new question, and share the details of what you tried; there's not enough info here for anyone to guess what went wrong.